# How to find google chrome absolute path in android

Tags: android, google-chrome-app

iam looking to get the path of google chrome on my android but didn't know how to find it on windows it's %AppData%..\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe but on my android didn't find how to get it

Comment: Try to access the [Chrome documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File). The parent of an abstract pathname may be obtained by invoking the [`getParent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getParent()) method of this class and consists of the pathname's prefix and each name in the pathname's name sequence except for the last. Each directory's absolute pathname is an ancestor of any `File` object with an absolute abstract pathname which begins with the directory's absolute pathname.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find all apk paths on this file "etc/apks_count_list.txt" on your android device.
Default path for Chrome is "system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk"

If you changed your default path and don't remember the new one, the apks_count_list.txt should have logged the new path.

Comment: did you mean `file:///storage/emulated/0/etc/apk_count_list.txt`